# Add new option to actions menu(wheel)

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a problem, i need add a new option to actions/setting menu for creating a new page, a similar option ,http://sharepointontop.blogspot.com.es/2013/03/create-custom-action-in-site.html .

My question is, is possible show/hide this option only for an user group in a determinated location.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can only use permissions with the Rights-parameter in CustomAction tag. Use this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx to get the right permission names.

Example:

```
Rights = "ManageLists"
```

--> users who can manage lists can see your menu entry